# Identifying redundant system RAM accumulation in a deep network grid search

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, ram

I am re-doing one of my Deep Learning course's assignments on RNN's, LSTM's and GRU's, mostly to deepen my own understanding.

By means of experiment, I want to do a grid search on a light-weight RNN model performing classification on MNIST-1D (https://github.com/greydanus/mnist1d) with some varying settings in hyperparameters I'm interested in (in this case, hidden size and learning rate). The code I use has three utility functions, namely train, test, and run incorporating both:

```
def train(train_loader, model, optimizer, criterion, device):
    """
    Trains network for one epoch in batches.

    Args:
        train_loader: Data loader for training set.
        model: Neural network model.
        optimizer: Optimizer (e.g. SGD).
        criterion: Loss function (e.g. cross-entropy loss).
    """

    avg_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    # Iterate through batches
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data

        # Move data to target device
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        # Zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Keep track of loss and accuracy
        avg_loss += loss
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    return avg_loss / len(train_loader), 100 * correct / total


def test(test_loader, model, criterion, device):
    """
    Evaluates network in batches.

    Args:
        test_loader: Data loader for test set.
        model: Neural network model.
        criterion: Loss function (e.g. cross-entropy loss).
    """

    avg_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    # Use torch.no_grad to skip gradient calculation, not needed for evaluation
    with torch.no_grad():
        # Iterate through batches
        for data in test_loader:
            # Get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = data

            # Move data to target device
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            # Keep track of loss and accuracy
            avg_loss += loss
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    return avg_loss / len(test_loader), 100 * correct / total

def run(rnn_type, epochs=100, hidden_size=20, lr=1e-2, write=False):
    """
    Run a test on MNIST-1D

    Args:
        rnn_type: can be either vanilla, gru or lstm
        epochs: number of epochs to run
        hidden_size: dimension of hidden state of rnn cell
    """
    # Create a writer to write to Tensorboard
    writer = SummaryWriter()

    if rnn_type == 'vanilla':
        rnn = VanillaRNN(1, hidden_size)
    elif rnn_type == 'gru':
        rnn = GRU(1, hidden_size)
    elif rnn_type == 'lstm':
        rnn = LSTM(1, hidden_size)
    else:
        raise Error('Unknown RNN type: ' + rnn_type)

    # Create classifier model
    model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('reshape', nn.Unflatten(1, (40, 1))),
        ('rnn', rnn),
        ('flat', nn.Flatten()),
        ('classifier', nn.Linear(40 * hidden_size, 10))
    ]))

    # Create loss function and optimizer
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=1e-3)

    # Use GPU if available
    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

    model = model.to(device)

    # Keep track of some relevant metrics
    train_losses = []
    train_accuracies = []
    test_losses = []
    test_accuracies = []

    for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):
        # Train on data
        train_loss, train_acc = train(train_loader,
                                      model,
                                      optimizer,
                                      criterion,
                                      device)

        # Test on data
        test_loss, test_acc = test(test_loader,
                                   model,
                                   criterion,
                                   device)

        if write:
          # Write metrics to Tensorboard
          writer.add_scalars('Loss', {
              'Train_{}'.format(rnn_type): train_loss,
              'Test_{}'.format(rnn_type): test_loss
          }, epoch)
          writer.add_scalars('Accuracy', {
              'Train_{}'.format(rnn_type): train_acc,
              'Test_{}'.format(rnn_type): test_acc
          }, epoch)

          print('\nFinished.')
          writer.flush()
          writer.close()

        train_losses.append(train_loss)
        train_accuracies.append(train_acc)
        test_losses.append(test_loss)
        test_accuracies.append(test_acc)

    metrics = {
        'tr_l': train_losses,
        'tr_a': train_accuracies,
        'te_l': test_losses,
        'te_a': test_accuracies
    }

    # Attempt to save some system RAM
    del model, criterion, optimizer, train_losses, train_accuracies, test_losses, test_accuracies
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    return metrics
```

Which I then use to run a quite straight-forward grid search:

```
def grid_search(values, epochs=100):
  """
  Performs grid search and returns run metrics for every parameter configuration

  Inputs:
  VALUES - iterable with parameter values, should correspond to params in terms
  of indexing
  """

  # Create grid
  grid = np.empty((len(values[0]), len(values[1])), dtype=object)

  # Iterate over grid
  for i, rate in enumerate(values[0]):
    for j, size in enumerate(values[1]):
      # Set attributes, calcualte model metrics, save in grid
      metrics = run('vanilla', epochs=epochs, hidden_size=size, lr=rate)
      grid[i,j] = metrics
      ### PERHAPS DO SOMETHING HERE? ###

  return grid
```

I would then like to use the grid to do some visualizations and check if I notice some realtions between things like learning rate and hidden size.

Problem is, I run this in Google Colab and the System RAM explodes after a grid or ten, twenty. I would like to run about 100 - 200 (every model takes about a 1.5 minute, so it's manageable), so ten to twenty doesn't cut it.

Some RAM accumulation is expected due to the actual metrics saved, but that should be quite negligible I suppose, since it's just a small numpy array.

I'm only interested in the grid metrics, not in the models resulting in them, so pretty much anything can go, except for the actual metrics, after running the `run` command.

I'd like to know where this RAM accumulation is coming from. I hypothesized it would be from the model itself (every grid requires instantiation of a model, so this requires a new chunk of RAM every time), but `del model` hardly reduces the RAM usage. What's my best approach to tackle this problem, and what would likely causes be?

I've added a '`### PERHAPS DO SOMETHING HERE? ###` there where I suspect some action is required.